# What exactly is react-native upgrade command doing? particularly to the gradle files?

Tags: react-native

I want to understand what the react-native upgrade command is doing, it sometimes changes the gradle files:

- android/app/build.gradle
- android/settings.gradle

Why does it asks if I want to Y/N to update does files? If I keep answering No is this gonna have bad impact on the application?

Comment: It's upgrading your project to the new RN version. For example, if new RN version is using higher Android SDK version, gradle file will be updated to the new version. This upgrade should be pretty safe, as it&#39;s performed using git, so in the worst case you will have a conflict but your code won't be harmed ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `upgrade` command is intended to run after updating RN version in existing projects (and after running `npm install` so the new version is in your `node_modules`).

Essentially, the command copies all files from the app template which is used to initialize a new RN app. The template is what you get when you run the `react-native init` command. This is also the reason why it needs to run after the new RN version is installed, because the templates app comes with the `react-native` dependency itself.

The reason that it asks you if you want to replace each modified file is that it doesn't know why the content has changed. It's possible that you made changes to a file yourself after you initialized your RN app.

If you haven't made any changes - it is safe to replace the existing files; it would be as if you got the file after initializing a new RN app. If you did modify a file - I think that you'd still like to see what changes were made in the new version (they can sometimes be required), in this case you can approve the replace (**assuming that you're using source control...**) so you can review the changes and in the worst case you can reset them if they're not necessary.

Alternatively, you can use [React Native Git Upgrade](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-git-upgrade) which can help you resolve conflicts more easily.